# Get file name from path Msbuild

Tags: file, path, msbuild, substring

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <fileName>$(FilePath.Substring($(FilePath.LastIndexOf('\'))))</fileName>    
</PropertyGroup>
```

I tried the above code. But am getting the file name including the last '\'. For eg. \Data.xml. I need only Data.xml. How can I get it?

Thank you...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could add another Substring call or so to strip the first character, but more convenient and less error-prone is to use the proper System.IO.Path function, see [Property Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2022):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <fileName>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName('$(FilePath)'))</fileName>    
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that items have the `%(Filename)` and `%(Extension)` [well known item metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-well-known-item-metadata):

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <Foo Include="@(Bar)" Filename="%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Note that this will return the filename *without extension* which is different from what the question is asking for.

Comment: @Craig thanks, I updated the answer accordingly.